# Hide A Parent But Not A Child In Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, show-hide

I need a way to hide a parent `<li>` but keep the child `<ul>` visible.

So for example I have the following code:

```
<li class="toplevel">Link
  <ul>
     <li class="secondlevel">Link</li>
  </ul>
<li>
```

Basically, I want the class toplevel to be hidden but the class secondlevel to be visible. Now I know I can do this with the css:

```
visibility:hidden / visibility:visible
```

But that keeps the height and width of the hidden class. What I need to use is more like:

```
display:none / display:inline
```

But of course, this doesn't work as the child isn't show and there isn't a way to make it re-show it appears.

Is there another method apart from using visibility to hide the parent but keep the child so that there is no height/width kept for the hidden parent?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided an example, as we'll be able to give you a more accurate solution fitted for your needs. http://www.jsfiddle.com is a good place to put an example.

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to hide `parent` and display it's `children`.

You can place toplevel Link which you want to hide into some inline tag:

```
<li class="toplevel"><span>Link</span>
    <ul>
        <li class="secondlevel">Link</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And then, set `display:none` for this tag:

```
li > span { display: none }
```

Comment: Bit hard to do with it being WordPress generated menus. Already had a ball ache getting them to display correctly now!

Comment: It is impossible to hide `parent` and display it's `children`. Of course, you can use `jQuery`, but it won't be "less hard". Anyway, if you want I can show possible solution, using `jQuery`.

Comment: As Edward tells you, this is just not possible. Another way of implementing your menu would be needed. The solution provided by Edward is actually really good, and the same *type* of solution used by Twitter Bootstrap to generate their navbars.

Comment: @user1544348, it's not that hard to make menus in Wordpress. You can easily inner-wrap the link text in anything you want - read the docs on nav menus - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu. $link_before & $link_after